# Полиморфные отношения в Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

Создал БД

> posts
>
> ```
> id - integer
> title - string
> body - text
> ```
>
> videos
>
> ```
> id - integer
> title - string
> url - string
> ```
>
> comments
>
> ```
> id - integer
> body - text
> commentable_id - integer
> commentable_type - string
> ```

Для каждой Модели определил отношения

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning commentable models.
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the post's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}

class Video extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the video's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

В контроллере написано

```
  public function index()
    {
        $comment = App\Comment::find(1);

        $commentable = $comment->commentable;
        dd( $commentable);
    }
```

Но мне выдает ошибку

> FatalErrorException in Model.php line 827: Class 'post' not found

В базе пробовал менять название commentable_type на Post все равно ошибка.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне сделать чтобы отношения работали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже того примера в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), который вы пытаетесь воспроизвести, написано, что Laravel хранит полное название класса (с пространством имён: `App\Post`)

Чтобы указать свои, сделайте так:

```
Relation::morphMap([
    'post' => 'App\Post',
    'video' => 'App\Video',
 // 'как-храним' => 'класс',
]);
```

Сделать это можно в `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::boot()`, например.